# Getting info from group with inner join

Tags: php, sql, function

In my application i'm trying to get information from users from different groups.

On group.php I have an overview of all the groups. Currently I'm just printing out the group name, but I also want to print out the avatars of the members like this:

4 avatars from members | Groupname

FUNCTION:

```
public function GetAllYourGroups($user_id) {
        $db = new Db();

        $select = "SELECT * FROM tblgroup_member WHERE user_id = $user_id";

        $result = $db -> conn -> query($select);
        $result_array=array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             $result_array[]=$row;                                                                                          
        }
        return $result_array;

    }
```

PHP:

```
$group = new Group();
$user = new User();
$groups= $group->GetAllYourGroups($user_id);
$user_id = $user -> getUserByEmail($email);

            foreach ($groups as $group) {


                    echo "<p  class='groupname'><a href='group.php?group_id=" . $group['group_id']. "'>" . $group['group_name']  . "</a></p>"; 

            }
```

With a new function I'm trying to get the avatars with 2 inner joins but I don't know how I can get the group_id that I was printing out in the previous function.

```
public function Getmembers($group_id) {
        $db = new Db();

            $select = "SELECT

                            g.group_id,
                            m.user_id,
                            u.avatar

                        FROM ((tblgroups g INNER JOIN tblgroup_member m ON g.group__id = m.group__id) INNER JOIN tblusers u ON u.user_id = m.user_id)
                        WHERE g.group_id = " .  $group_id . " ";



        $result = $db -> conn -> query($select);
        $result_array=array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             $result_array[]=$row;                                                                                          
        }
        return $result_array;

    }
```

Here are the tables that I'm using:

**tblgroups**
- group_id

**tblgroup_member:**
- group_id
- User_id

**tblusers**
- user_id
- avatar

Comment: Hi Lisa, I don't quite understand what your problem is. You appear to be selecting the `group_id` with that query. However, you don't need the joins. The query in your second function should read something like `SELECT m.group_id, m.user_id, u.avatar FROM tblgroup_member m, tblusers u WHERE m.user_id = u.user_id and m.group_id = ...`

Comment: I'm trying to print out the avatars from members of a group. At this moment i can print out all the members (first function) but to print out the avatars i need a join i think? The avatars are coming from another group. 

In the second function i'm trying to get the avatars but i don't know how i can get the group_id that i was printing out at my first function ...

Comment: Well in the second function, you are returning all of the members based on a specific `group_id` in the `$group_id` parameter, so you shouldn't even need to return the `group_id` from the database - all rows in the results would have the same `group_id`. Regardless, the query I wrote above will have `(group_id, user_id, avatar)` as columns in the results. That should be all the info you need.

Comment: Yes but the problem is how to found the group_id

Comment: Btw: you get information out of 3 columns without an inner join? Is this possible?!

Comment: The query I wrote is the same thing as doing an inner join, it's just more readable in this particular case IMO. I still have no idea what you're actually trying to ask, I think you need to explain better. The `group_id` is stored in `$group['group_id']` in your second code snippet above.